# Recursive function call, with array of strings as argument in C

Tags: c, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to solve a problem on code-wars using a recursive (first time trying recursion) function call that is taking an array of strings as an argument. On the initial function call the code runs through, however on the first recursive call I get a segmentation fault when the for loop runs.
I assume there is something not quite right with how I am passing the reduced array back in to the function however I am having trouble finding help online with this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_LEN 6

int cancelPairs(const char dir1, const char dir2) {
    switch(dir1) {
    case 'N':
        return (dir2 == 'S') ? 1 : 0;
    case 'S':
        return (dir2 == 'N') ? 2 : 0;
    case 'E':
        return (dir2 == 'W') ? 3 : 0;
    case 'W':
        return (dir2 == 'E') ? 4 : 0;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}

const char **dirReduc(
  const char *const array[/*length_in*/], 
  int length_in, 
  int *l_out
) {
    static int l_in;                        // Track last reduction out count 
    char * reduced[length_in][STR_LEN];     // Store reduced array objects

    int add_last = 0, cursor = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length_in; i++) {
        if (i == length_in - 1 && add_last) { // Add last array object if not part of a canceled pair
            strcpy(reduced[cursor++], array[i]);
        } else {                              // Cancel pairs or add to reduced array
            if (cancelPairs(array[i][0], array[i+1][0])) {
                printf("Cancelling %s & %s\n", array[i], array[i+1]);
                i++;                              // Cancel pairs by incrementing i (skip over)
            } else {
                if (i == length_in - 2) add_last = 1; // Set add_last flag
                strcpy(reduced[cursor++], array[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (l_in == cursor) {                   // No further reduction possible
        printf("Cannot reduce any further, malloc and return\n");
        return (const char**)array;           // Return input array for now, will fix later
    } else {
        l_in = cursor;
        dirReduc(reduced, cursor, l_out);
    }

    // return (const char**)array;
}

int main(void) {
    int length_out;
    const char *const test1[] = {"NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"}; // 7
    const char *const test2[] = {"NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST"}; // 4
    const char *const test3[] = {"NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST", "NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST", "SOUTH", "NORTH"};   // 10
    const char **reduced = dirReduc(test3, 10, &length_out);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried hacking my way through it for some time to no avail, I also have warnings show up when I compile such as:
[compilation warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m5a5.jpg) but when I make the warnings go away say by doing `strcpy(*reduced[cursor++], array[i]);` I get segmentation faults, so I just put up with the warnings however I am not sure if this is OK?

Comment: When you declare a function to return a value, it must have an explicit `return` statement in all paths the function can take. Your `dirReduc` function does *not* do that. Which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also note that because your `dirReduc` function stores internal state in a `static` local variable (`l_in`) it can't be used more than once.

Comment: _"so I just put up with the warnings however I am not sure if this is OK?"_ - No, it's not. In fact, put the compiler in even stricter mode to make some of those warnings in to hard errors. With `gcc` and `clang`, use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`

Comment: Suggest something like `enum dir {N,E,S,W}` and keep the size and the array tougher, maybe, `struct dirs { size_t size; enum dir array[]; }` (FAM). Strings are not the cleanest way, and will probably confuse you when you are debugging.

Comment: Also, the `const` means it is read-only, changing it is UB; get rid of the second `const`. `reduced` needs `memcpy` with the `length_in`, not `strcpy` which is only for NUL-terminated strings. But you could easily make it in-place by backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if (l_in == cursor) {                   // No further reduction possible
>     printf("Cannot reduce any further, malloc and return\n");
>     return (const char**)array;           // Return input array for now, will fix later
> } else {
>     l_in = cursor;
>     dirReduc(reduced, cursor, l_out);
> }
> ```

In your else path you have no return. You do call the function recursively, but then you disregard its return value and exit the function without returning. The return statement in the recursive call does not return a value from the *caller*.

You likely meant to write the following.

```
if (l_in == cursor) {                   // No further reduction possible
    printf("Cannot reduce any further, malloc and return\n");
    return (const char**)array;           // Return input array for now, will fix later
} else {
    l_in = cursor;
    return dirReduc(reduced, cursor, l_out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took into account all of the comments and made the appropriate changes, however the actual issue was that I was accessing memory outside of the array bounds on recursive calls.
I ended up abandoning this approach in favor of a while loop and used realloc to shrink the array down until it fully reduced.

```
  *l_out = len_in;
  int reducible = 1;

  while (reducible) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len_in - 1; ++i) {
      if (len_in <= 1) break;
      if (cancelPairs(strings[i][0], strings[i+1][0])) {
        char *can1, *can2;
        can1 = strings[i], can2 = strings[i+1];
        
        // Shorten array
        for (int n = i; n < len_in - 1; ++n) {
          strings[n] = strings[n+2];
          printf("n is %d\n", n);
        }
        free(can1); free(can2);
        i--; // Invalidate i incrementation
        len_in -= 2;
        break;
      } 
    }
    if (len_in == *l_out) reducible = 0; else {
      *l_out = len_in;
      strings = realloc(strings, len_in * sizeof (char*));
    }
  }
```